# SSRS MS words report with page break

Tags: x++, ax

i am currently working with Dynamic AX and is exporting a SSRS report in MS words format.

What i need on my end is to allow the report to have conditional page break using X++ codes. I  only have a black line across the page which does not break it on a UI level.

Any code i should use to implement a page break at code level ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean in your data provider table computed in you DP class, then test the flag in SSRS.

Comment: Hey Jan, thanks for the reply. Please pardon me for my knowledge in this area. Could you explain alittle more about what a flag is ? Does that mean i have to write some codes ? If so, could you provide some sample to these codes ?

Comment: A flag is a boolean or NoYes value indicating where a breakpoint should be emitted. And yes, you have to set it your self by X++ code as you wanted. And no I cannot give any clues how to do this, as you have provided no background context to do so.